# Как преобразовать string или datetime.month в int?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void ShomMonthYear(DateTime mY)
        {
            int m, y;
            int sum = 0;
            string str, coin;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                str = sr.ReadLine();
                m = Convert.ToInt32(str[3] + str[4]);
                y = Convert.ToInt32(str[6] + str[7] + str[8] + str[9]);
                if ((m == mY.Month) && (y == mY.Year))
                {
                    coin = str.Split(' ')[2];
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(coin);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Суммарный расход за указанный месяц составил: " + sum);
        }
```

Необходимо преобразовать месяц даты в int. Входная строка из потока выглядит следующим образом: "12.09.2022 111111"  где до пробела идёт дата, а после пробела идёт число. Необходимо из даты сделать число, делаю его преобразуя подстроку "09" в число, но используя Convert.ToInt32 я из "09" получаю не 9 а 105.
Как сделать правильно? Или может есть конвертер из строки в дату?

Comment: Покажите вашу входную строку. Convert.ToInt32("09") возвращает "9" как и ожидается.

Comment: m = convert.toint32(str[3]+str[4]);

Comment: Я также советую вам посмотреть substring метод у класса string, чтобы не писать str[3] + str[4] и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще лучше всего парсить первую часть в datetime, и из него получать нужные данные:

```
var str = "12.09.2022 111111";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(str.Split(' ')[0]);
Console.WriteLine(date.Month);
```

Answer (score 1):

> но используя Convert.ToInt32 я из "09" получаю не 9 а 105

Сложение двух `char` дает `int` равное сумме кодов этих символов.

```
string str = "12.09.2022 111111";
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", str[3] + str[4], (str[3] + str[4]).GetType().FullName);
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", "" + str[3] + str[4], ("" + str[3] + str[4]).GetType().FullName);
```

Вывод:

```
105 - System.Int32
09 - System.String
```